# problemas para listar un json con fetch en javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json, fetch

estoy haciendo un cliente en javaScript para consumir un servicio web RestFul, tengo un metodo para listar el json que me devuelve el servicio, el método es así:

```
const tabla = document.querySelector('#lista-pacientes tbody');
function listarPacientes(){
    fetch('http://localhost:7101/AplicacionServidorREST-ProyectoServidorREST-context-root/resources/model/listar')
      .then(respuesta =>respuesta.json()) 
       .then(pacientes => {
         pacientes.forEach(paciente=> {
           const row  = document.createElement('tr'); 
           row.innerHTML +=   `
           <td>${paciente.id}</td> 
           <td>${paciente.documento}</td> 
           <td>${paciente.nombre}</td> 
           <td>${paciente.correo}</td> 
           <td>${paciente.telefono}</td> 
           <td>${paciente.genero}</td> 
           `;
          tabla.appendChild(row);
        
         });
         
        })

        .catch(error => console.log('Hubo un error : ' + error.message))
}
```

Funciona parfectamente, pero solo cuando el json tiene el siguiente formato

```
[{"correo":"luis@gmail.com","documento":"66666","genero":"masculino","id":2,"nombre":"Neymar","telefono":"66666"},{"correo":"paul@gmail.com","documento":"77777","genero":"masculino","id":3,"nombre":"cr7","telefono":"7777"},
```

Sin embargo ahora necesitar listar un json que primero me devuelve un objeto y luego el array

```
{"Paciente":[{"correo":"nuevo","documento":"nuevo","genero":"nuevo","id":"1","nombre":"nuevo","telefono":"nuevo"},{"correo":"aaa","documento":"aaa","genero":"aaa","id":"6","nombre":"aaa","telefono":"aaa"},
```

Alguien sabe que debo modificar para que funcione con el segundo json? Lo agredeceria mucho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplemente sería anteponer el objeto al arreglo antes de realizar el loop

```
pacientes.Paciente.forEach(item => {
   //codigo...
})
```

Sólo es cosa de navegar por sus niveles ;)

Nos comentas si te sirvió!

Comment: Efectivamente sirvió, muchas gracias. disculpa la molestia, pero ahora podrias decirme como listar un solo objecto? es que el servidor en el cual hice ese codigo me devolvia siempre un json array y ese metodo me servia para todo, ahora el servidor que estoy consumiento me devuelve el json de forma diferente, por ejemplo como haria para listar esto?  `   {"Paciente":{"correo":"falcao","documento":"falcao","genero":"masculino","id":"3","nombre":"falcao","telefono":"falcao"}}`, ya intente lo mismo que dijiste, pero en este caso no sirve.

Comment: Tienes que tener clara la diferencia entre un objeto y un arreglo. [Acá](https://www.codecademy.com/forum_questions/53a7ba31548c351d0c00706a) tienes una buena explicación. De todas maneras para acceder a las propiedades del objeto sería `Paciente.correo`, etc. No olvides marcar la respuesta como correcta si te fue útil ;)

Comment: Si es un solo registro, entonces accedes con `pacientes.Paciente[0]`, por ejemplo: `console.log(pacientes.Paciente[0].correo);`. Si tienes dos o más registros, vas a tener que recorrerlos hasta encontrar el que quieres mostrar.